# convert character array of numbers to integers

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am creating a console program that asks for users to input integers between 0 and 100 and then outputs each number and how many times is was entered. Each number the user enters is separated by a space and input ends when 0 is entered. So far i am using `cin.getline` to store the numbers in a character array. This limits the ability to manipulate the numbers as they are stored as ascii characters. If the user types in 10 i want to be able to store 10 into a new array as a single integer, such as `s[i]=converted_number`.

Comment: how do i take the elements in a character array which are numbers and convert them into integers. all i need is a way to take one array pointer like s[0] and convert its value such as '0' into an integer of 0 and store it in another array. sorry for not being specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `cin.getline` simply do:

```
int input;
while( cin >> input, input != 0 )
{
    ...do computations or store it somewhere...
}
```

That will get you the input in integer form.

Comment: very true. and i started out that way. but cin stops at spaces.

Comment: @user999861: That's why you call it multiple times, each time extracts a different (space separated) integer value. When the input is 0 you break the loop.

Comment: ok i see where you are going with this. i missed reading that its looped. ill see if i that works.

Comment: @user999861: If it answers your question, mark it as so by clicking the check next to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but boost has a nice thing for that. It's called `lexical_cast`. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm

Comment: i have been reading post after post with boost as the solution. i would jump on that but im a student and im doing this for a class. im not sure that will be allowed. i appreciate the input tho.

Comment: Boost is THE C++ library (not counting STL), I don't know a lot of C++ Software that does not use it why should it not be allowed? Other than that there is still `itoa()` (not part of the C++ standard) and using `cin` in a type safe way like K-ballo suggested.

Comment: @krynr Boost might be THE c++ library, but when it comes to learning/teaching the language itself, most of Boost is very counterproductive as is much of the std:: itself. It does not produce the correct instincts to problem solving. This should have been apparent from OP.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Quite the contrary, if you want to learn good C++ you should use and *read* boost and STL. However, if you mean learning/teaching how a computer works, that's a different question...